# How to perform FFT on stored digital data

Tags: matlab, fft

I have to do FFT in MATLAB on the digital sinusoidal data that is stored in excel. please find the amplitude values of the sine wave discrete signal stored in the Lookup table.

> Number of points : 256
>
> Maximum amplitude : 1024
>
> Numbers per row: 1

Numbers are in decimal

```
512, 525, 537, 550, 562, 575, 587, 600, 612, 624, 636, 649, 661, 673, 684, 696, 708, 719, 731, 742, 753, 764, 775, 786, 796, 807, 817, 827, 837, 846, 856, 865, 874, 883, 891, 900, 908, 916, 923, 931, 938, 945, 951, 957, 964, 969, 975, 980, 985, 990, 994, 998, 1002, 1005, 1009, 1012, 1014, 1016, 1018, 1020, 1022, 1023, 1023, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1023, 1023, 1022, 1020, 1018, 1016, 1014, 1012, 1009, 1005, 1002, 998, 994, 990, 985, 980, 975, 969, 964, 957, 951, 945, 938, 931, 923, 916, 908, 900, 891, 883, 874, 865, 856, 846, 837, 827, 817, 807, 796, 786, 775, 764, 753, 742, 731, 719, 708, 696, 684, 673, 661, 649, 636, 624, 612, 600, 587, 575, 562, 550, 537, 525, 512, 499, 487, 474, 462, 449, 437, 424, 412, 400, 388, 375, 363, 351, 340, 328, 316, 305, 293, 282, 271, 260, 249, 238, 228, 217, 207, 197, 187, 178, 168, 159, 150, 141, 133, 124, 116, 108, 101, 93, 86, 79, 73, 67, 60, 55, 49, 44, 39, 34, 30, 26, 22, 19, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 19, 22, 26, 30, 34, 39, 44, 49, 55, 60, 67, 73, 79, 86, 93, 101, 108, 116, 124, 133, 141, 150, 159, 168, 178, 187, 197, 207, 217, 228, 238, 249, 260, 271, 282, 293, 305, 316, 328, 340, 351, 363, 375, 388, 400, 412, 424, 437, 449, 462, 474, 487, 499
```

I have tried writing code in MATLAB but I am not getting the exact output. lease tell me the coding procedure to obtain FFT.

Comment: Why not use fft()? Or are you supposed to write your own implementation of a DFT/FFT? If you just want other users to provide code, then this question is off-topic on this site and will be closed.

Comment: What output do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: This might help: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20212/time-domain-data-into-fft-using-matlab/20223#20223