# Sinc Interpolation implementation in Matlab for reconstructing or interpolating?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

I am working on my project and I need to have a Sinc Interpolation function for a real world image. But, it seems that I have not caught the concept of Sinc interpolation. Could some one help me with this issue? this function is for adding some value among samples or it is used for reconstructing? How can I use this function for reconstructing signal.

Comment: the $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ function is the impulse response to an ideal, theoretical, brick-wall LPF which is used in the Nyquist/Shannon/Whitaker Sampling and Reconstruction Theorem to reconstruct the bandlimited continuous-time waveform from the samples.  so the interpolation concept is the same as the reconstruction concept and then sampling the continuous-time reconstructed at different times than the original samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in MatLab, but have done it using C++. So I am not in a position to provide you any matlab code example or snippet, however I will direct you to some links that will help you clear your doubts and concepts regarding the sinc function, filtering and reconstruction.

Sinc function is basically used for low pass filtering signals and for reconstruction of the signal using the previous or old samples. Check out these links, It will clear your concepts about sinc function such as how its used for low pass filtering and reconstruction.

*concept of sinc function* :- http://www.dspguide.com/ch11/2.htm

*Low pass filtering* :- http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch16.pdf

*Reconstruction is done through interpolation*, check :- [What is an algorithm to re-sample from a variable rate to a fixed rate?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/what-is-an-algorithm-to-re-sample-from-a-variable-rate-to-a-fixed-rate/8502#8502)

There are already loads of discussion here about sinc functions, sinc windowing filters, interpolation techniques, reconstruction etc. Reading them will certainly help you clear your doubts and concepts regarding these. Hope this helps.